# Assigning value to a huge data table element too slow

Tags: r, performance, data.table

Given a data.table defined as follow:

```
n <- 34916339
ds2 <- data.table(X=rep(as.integer(NA),n), Y=rep(as.integer(NA),n), 
                  LAT=rep(as.numeric(NA),n), LON=rep(as.numeric(NA),n),
                  FCT_DATE=rep(as.Date(NA),n), VAR=rep(as.character(NA),n), 
                  TYPE=rep(as.character(NA),n), VALUE=rep(as.numeric(NA),n))
```

The following code is too slow.

```
ds = data.table dim = 572399 x 66
colNames <- rep("any_string",66)  # only an example

for (i in 1:nrow(ds)) {
   for (j in 6:66) {
       colName <- colNames[j]
       colName.split <- strsplit(colName, "_")    # Split the elements by "_"   

       k <- ((i-1) * length(colIndex))+(j-5)  # creates 61 lines each complete loop
       ds2[k,6] <- colName.split[[1]][1]      
       ds2[k,7] <- colName.split[[1]][2]      # so, it reads 61 cols from ds
       ds2[k,8] <- ds[i,get(colName)]         # and creates 61 lines in ds2
   }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can improve this code? In particular, the attributions to cols 6,7 and 8 are slow. I'm trying to convert the 66 columns of the data.table ds to a 8 column data.table.

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED:**

```
# Building of an example of the data.table ds (the faster way I know for the moment)
ds <- data.table(1:nds,1:nds,rep(3.3,nds),rep(4.4,nds),rep(as.Date("2014-08-16"),nds))
for (i in 1:61) {
  ds <- cbind(ds,rep(i+i/10,nds))
}

# setting the real names
names.ds <- c("X","Y","LAT","LON","FCT_DATE",
      "UVES_01N","VVES_01N","PSNM_01N","PREC_01N","UVES_01P","VVES_01P","PSNM_01P","PREC_01P",
      "UVES_02N","VVES_02N","PSNM_02N","PREC_02N","UVES_02P","VVES_02P","PSNM_02P","PREC_02P",
      "UVES_03N","VVES_03N","PSNM_03N","PREC_03N","UVES_03P","VVES_03P","PSNM_03P","PREC_03P",
      "UVES_04N","VVES_04N","PSNM_04N","PREC_04N","UVES_04P","VVES_04P","PSNM_04P","PREC_04P",
      "UVES_05N","VVES_05N","PSNM_05N","PREC_05N","UVES_05P","VVES_05P","PSNM_05P","PREC_05P",
      "UVES_06N","VVES_06N","PSNM_06N","PREC_06N","UVES_06P","VVES_06P","PSNM_06P","PREC_06P",
      "UVES_07N","VVES_07N","PSNM_07N","PREC_07N","UVES_07P","VVES_07P","PSNM_07P","PREC_07P",
      "UVES_AVN","VVES_AVN","PSNM_AVN","PREC_AVN","PREC_OBS")
setnames(ds, old=1:66, new=names.ds)
```

My goal is to convert it to a data.table like this:

```
    X  Y      LAT      LON   FCT_DATE  VAR TYPE   VALUE
1: 312 54 -39.7401 -68.4375 2009-01-02 UVES  01N    0.63
2: 312 54 -39.7401 -68.4375 2009-01-02 VVES  01N   -3.17
3: 312 54 -39.7401 -68.4375 2009-01-02 PSNM  01N 1019.52
...
34916339: 341 83 -39.7401 -68.4375 2009-01-02 PREC  OBS    0.50
```

Comment: Can you provide some small example of `ds` and your desired output?

Comment: Two problems with that code: a) it's not vectorized, but that's easy to fix; b) there is no indexing of the columns and so you are over-writing columns 6-8 every time through that inner loop. The final value would simply be the results from column 66 in the original dataset: I'm guessing you want to increment the column index by three every time though the loop (or perhaps you somehow want to stack, but you never described the goal.

Comment: Why not create a matrix `mat` initially, and then do `data.table(mat)` when it's ready?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `<-` on a `data.table`.  Use `:=` or `set` instead.  See `?set`

Comment: Tks BondeDust, the code was really wrong (EDITED). For each 61 cols from ds I want to create 61 lines in ds2 (the first 5 cols will have the same value in these 61 lines). But concretely, what does "there is no indexing of the columns" mean? What should I've done and why it would help me.

Comment: Hi Richard, I've tried to build a matrix with the same dim but I had to restart the R session because the prompt didn't come back. I made a version based on 8 vectors and it behaved much faster than using data.table but I want to insist on it because I chose to work with data.table due to its speed and I need to know how to manipulate it properly.

Comment: @GSee, tks my loop version really run much faster only changing `<-` to `set()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a faster way. The other answer calls `sub(...)` twice for each row. There's no need to do that since these are just the column names, and there are only 66 of them. Using your code with `nds <- 1e6` to create `ds`, the code below runs about 20X faster.

```
library(reshape2)
# code from other answer
system.time({ 
  ds2 <- melt(ds, 1:5, variable.name = "VAR", value.name = "VALUE")
  ds2[, VAR := as.character(VAR)]
  ds2[, `:=`(TYPE = sub(".*_", "", VAR), VAR = sub("_.*", "", VAR))]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#  239.43    1.05  240.78 

# this code does not call sub(...) 2 million times
system.time({
  cn <- strsplit(colnames(ds)[6:66],"_")
  ds3 <- melt(ds,1:5,variable.name="VAR",value.name="VALUE")
  ds3[,":="(VAR =rep(sapply(cn,"[",1),each=nrow(ds)),
            TYPE=rep(sapply(cn,"[",2),each=nrow(ds)))]  
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   13.87    8.96   22.83 

identical(ds2,ds3)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: AMAZING @jlhoward, what a improvement! You guys know what to do. Another core tool to know is the apply-like functions. It took 3s here. I can't even take some coffee now. Tks and I LOVE YOU too.

Comment: I knew there had to be a better way. Well done. I'm always leery of ordering-dependent operations, but really that's just my paranoia and inexperience talking, since the input ordering is perfectly reliable... and when in doubt, unit test.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're trying to reinvent the wheel. This works:

```
library(reshape2)
ds2 <- melt(ds, 1:5, variable.name = "VAR", value.name = "VALUE")
ds2[, VAR := as.character(VAR)]
ds2[, `:=`(TYPE = sub(".*_", "", VAR), VAR = sub("_.*", "", VAR))]
```

It *was* fairly slow on just 1,000,000 rows (on a MacBook Pro w/ OS 10.9, 2.8 GHz i7):

```
 #   user  system elapsed 
 # 73.373   1.398  74.809
```

but at least it's parsimonious and readable. You also didn't say how slow "too slow" was, so I have no idea if this is an improvement. A `strsplit`-based solution took even longer (> 100 seconds), and `stringr::str_match_all` longer than that.

Comment: FANTASTIC @ssdecontrol, FANTASTIC. I LOVE YOU. That is what I was looking for. "too slow" means I could not wait that long because the dataset will probably be regenerated until the final version. This code took 60s to run (MB Air OSX 10.8.5 2GHz i7 8GB RAM). There are so many libs to R but reshape2 for sure is one to be explored. Tks.

Comment: @JRMGarcia Glad to hear it. Side note: I must have something wrong with my R installation if you're beating my benchmarks on an Air, on a dataset 30x bigger than the one I used.

Comment: I'm used to clean the memory before manipulating such a big dataset with `rm(list = ls())`, `gc()` and `purge` (SO command). Your code on my dataset `dim(ds) [1] 572400  66` resulted in `user  system elapsed`--> `2.514   0.601   3.115`. R version=3.1.1. Maybe these can help.

Comment: I just upgraded from 3.1.0 to 3.1.1, and ran both `gc` and `purge` first. Got `75.843   1.169  77.011` on this run, again with 1,000,000 rows. I'm going to ask a question on SuperUser about how to go about diagnosing what I'm doing wrong. In any case, the timings for the other answer's code were `3.264   0.795   4.074`.